# Count number of orders, paymentRatio, return rate and date of last order per customer with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
|customerNum|OrderNumber|ArticleNumber|PaymentType|Returned?|OrderDate |
|1          |1          |1            |cash       |Yes      |01.01.2016|
|2          |2          |3            |credit     |No       |30.02.2016|
|1          |1          |2            |cash       |No       |01.01.2016|
|2          |2          |4            |credit     |Yes      |30.02.2016|
|3          |3          |2            |credit     |No       |17.05.2016|
|2          |4          |8            |cash       |Yes      |19.08.2016|
```

Expected Outcome:

```
customerNum|Numb.ofOrdersTot|ratioCash/CreditPayment|returnRate|LastOrder |
|1         |1               |1                      |0,5       |01.01.2016|
|2         |2               |0.5                    |0,66      |19.08.2016|
|3         |1               |0                      |0         |17.05.2016|
```

I want to count the total number of orders (not ordered articles) per customer (one Order can have more than one article), the ratio of cash payment and credit payment (number of cash payments / number of credit payments (one order with more than one article has the same payment method)) the return rate of customer (numberOfReturnedArticles/numberOfArticlesOrderedbycustomerTotal) and last order date

I tried already a part of it already but this is not working and not complete:

```
`COUNT(*) AS Numb.ofOrdersTot,(COUNT(orderNumber)/COUNT(Returned? = Yes)) FROM table 1 group by customerNum;`
```

PLZ help me: it´s very important :/

Comment: Even parts of the solution would help me :)

Comment: There are many error in your question: There are 2 Order of Customer 1, The date are wrong. there is no 2019-02-30. if the orderdate field from type DATE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my Answer. please check it and look if the fields have the right type. Also i have add 2 second field 'orderdate2' with a other format. you can remove one. so your 'Expected Outcome' cant be from your input

```
SELECT
    customerNum AS 'customerNum'
    , SUM(1) AS 'Numb.ofOrdersTot'
    , SUM(IF(`PaymentType` = 'credit',1,0)) / SUM(1) AS 'ratioCash/CreditPayment'
    , SUM(IF(`Returned?` = 'Yes',1,0)) / SUM(1) AS 'returnRate'
    ,MAX(`OrderDate`) AS 'LastOrder'
    ,DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`OrderDate`),'%d.%m.%Y') AS 'LastOrder2'   
FROM orders
GROUP BY customerNum;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM orders;
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| id | customerNum | OrderNumber | ArticleNumber | PaymentType | Returned? | OrderDate  |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |           1 |           1 |             1 | cash        | Yes       | 2016-01-01 |
|  2 |           2 |           2 |             3 | credit      | No        | 2016-02-29 |
|  3 |           1 |           1 |             2 | cash        | No        | 2016-01-01 |
|  4 |           2 |           2 |             4 | credit      | Yes       | 2016-02-29 |
|  5 |           3 |           3 |             2 | credit      | No        | 2016-05-17 |
|  6 |           2 |           4 |             8 | cash        | Yes       | 2016-08-19 |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     customerNum AS 'customerNum'
    ->     , SUM(1) AS 'Numb.ofOrdersTot'
    ->     , SUM(IF(`PaymentType` = 'credit',1,0)) / SUM(1) AS 'ratioCash/CreditPayment'
    ->     , SUM(IF(`Returned?` = 'Yes',1,0)) / SUM(1) AS 'returnRate'
    ->     ,MAX(`OrderDate`) AS 'LastOrder'
    ->     ,DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`OrderDate`),'%d.%m.%Y') AS 'LastOrder2'
    -> FROM orders
    -> GROUP BY customerNum;
+-------------+------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| customerNum | Numb.ofOrdersTot | ratioCash/CreditPayment | returnRate | LastOrder  | LastOrder2 |
+-------------+------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|           1 |                2 |                  0.0000 |     0.5000 | 2016-01-01 | 01.01.2016 |
|           2 |                3 |                  0.6667 |     0.6667 | 2016-08-19 | 19.08.2016 |
|           3 |                1 |                  1.0000 |     0.0000 | 2016-05-17 | 17.05.2016 |
+-------------+------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Why is the expected outcome different? Your mistake or theirs?

Comment: @Strawberry - there a 2 order from customer 1 ,and the date are wrong 30.02.2016 in his sample data

Comment: Big Thanks for your support!